# Working with large Visual Studio oriented codebase

Tags: filetype-c++, makeprg

I have been using Vim for about 2 years on my personal C++ project on Ubuntu with great success. I build using `g++` and `make`, as my build system. In vim, I can build the project without problem using `:make`. My personal project has about 200 files.

In my job, the project I'm working on has 7 millions C++ files (over 35k files) and has been, from day one, a project build for Microsoft Windows, using Visual Studio. I have installed `vim` at my job, trying to use it to code. So far, I have not been able to "integrate" it successfully to my workflow for two main reasons:

1. *Finding files is ridiculously slow*: on my personal project, using `:find` is instantaneous. I can use wildcard without problems, I get nice fuzzy file search right out of the box. For finding expressions, I can use `grep` or `vimgrep` and results come out fast. On my job's code base, finding a file or an expression can take from couple seconds to 30+ seconds. We have "a lot" of nested directories.
2. *I'm unable to make `:make` work appropriately*: I have tried using `makeprg` and `denvenv` and `msbuild` (see [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/can-i-use-vim-with-visual-studio) for example), with no success. Building a single file (as `Ctrl+F7` does within Visual Studio) would suffice, but I can't seem to make it work.

If I could make work both 1. and 2., I would be satisfied. I could do about 90% of my editing/compiling from `vim`. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

Notes:

- I have used `VsVim` for some time. It is not so bad (in fact it's pretty great) but is not enough for me. Some options are missing (the vim help, for instance).
- We work on Windows 10/11 and use Visual Studio 2022.
- For the 2. I have tried a lot of things. The last thing I tried is this:

  ```
  au FileType cpp set makeprg=devenv\ MySolution.sln\ /build\ "Debug|x64"
  au FileType cpp set errorformat=\ %#%f(%l)\ :\ %#%t%[A-z]%#\ %m
  ```

  The command works in the terminal (it builds the solution and I see the output). From `vim`. When I type `:make` nothing seems to happen and I get the following output in the terminal:

  ```
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (devenv MySolution.sln /build   ^>C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Temp\VIe1D01.tmp 2^>^&1)
  ```

  Then vim "hangs" and if I go check the specified `tmp` file, I see the build output. In my personal project, I see the build output directly in Vim.

Comment: Regarding problem #1, could you show us the relevant part of your config AND a reasonably realist minimal reproducible example? Regarding problem #2, could you show us what you tried? Do `devenv` and/or `msbuild` work for you outside of Vim?

Comment: Please include `:setlocal path?` for a file from which `:find` is slow; it wasn't designed to be used for fuzzy-finding, so if you have lots of files and `path=**/*`, it can be slow.

Comment: May I ask why `:make` doesn't work? Are you getting an error message? What happens if you exeucte it?

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Reading the question again, it might have been a better idea to split it into two questions. One for each problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers. I'm sorry I cannot give a quicker feedback. I'm having a big week and I haven't yet had time to sit down and dive into the details of each answer. Rest assured I will come back to this really soon. I will also add any necessary details.

Comment: Take your time. Maybe the best answer wasn't written yet.

Comment: You may also want to look into the Windows versions of indexing tools such as [GNU global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/), [ctags](https://ctags.io/) and [cscope](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cscope/). Although LSP support will give you the same benefit and more.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What if you move your build commands into a batch file (e.g. `make.bat`) does it work better. The command line parsing when the command contains quotes is tricky? Did you make sure the shell from which you start vim has all the environment variables need to use msbuilt (`vsvars32.bat` has been called)?

Comment: Do you still have something open in this question? How can we help you better? If one solution address your problem maybe could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: I have had time to try some elements for building using the :make command but couldn't make it work so far. A lot of these elements are new to me and I have limited time at my job to investigate this. I will come back with some details at some point. Don't worry, I am going to give feedback.

Comment: Can't suggest anything for `make` except say that the only time I used VS is for compiling neovim and I used cmake to generate the VS project then used `:let &mp = "cmake --build build/debug"` and it integrated with quickfix without issue.  About the first requirement though, this is what I do.  For stable codebases, you don't create new source/header files often.  Mostly you need to search+open git-tracked files.  What I do is have a text file populated with the output of `git ls-files`, which I can pull up with a keymap, then I `/` for the file I'm looking for, and `gf` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to post my own answer to share my actual setup, which is highly based on the discussion we have had here. Thanks to all who helped.

## 1. Fuzzy file search

Although [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) works very well for searching identifiers (I have tried it and speed no longer is an issue. It's really fast), it does not fuzzy search for files in the way I was able to do it using the `:find` command hack. By doing some research, I found a plugin called [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) which does fuzzy search for files really well. At first, I had problem with it. I did not work as expected out of the box and I had to tweak it a little bit.

Here is my current CtrlP configuration, which works well for me:

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode=''       " Use vim's current directory as the root.
let g:ctrlp_max_files=0                " Do not apply a maximum number of files to scan.
let g:ctrlp_max_depth=10000            " Maximum number of directories to recursively search into.
let g:ctrlp_match_window='results:100' " Keep the result window dimensions, but show up to 100 results (scrollable).
let g:ctrlp_by_filename=1              " Enable filename mode by default.
let g:ctrlp_regexp=1                   " Enable regex mode by default.
```

We have a lot of nested directories and over 35K files, so these settings were mandatory to get workable results in the find list. The only drawback I can see it that because I am using regex mode, search is a bit slower and typing very fast and seeing results appear "real time" does not work. It's not snappy and there is even some lag as you add characters, but it's fast enough, in my opinion, for what I have to do and it's the best solution I have so far.

## 2. Building a single file

For this one, I have @Vivian De Smedt to thank for a lot. I came up with this custom compiler plugin which seems to work well:

```
" This option must be set to override the default files.
let current_compiler="MSBuild"

" Define :CompilerSet for older version of Vi, which do not have it defined by default.
if exists(":CompilerSet") != 2
  command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
endif

" By default, this compiler plugin builds the current file. This is similar to hitting
" Ctrl + F7 in Visual Studio. The Error format string was shamelessly stolen from
" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621753/6575139 and seems to work well.
let configuration="Debug" " Other option : Release.
let platform="x64"

CompilerSet makeprg=MSBuild\ %:p:h\ /noLogo\ /p:Configuration=Debug\ /p:Platform=x64\ /t:ClCompile\ /p:SelectedFiles=%:t
CompilerSet errorformat=\ %#%f(%l\\\,%c):\ %m
```

This will build the current file in x64|Debug using MSBuild. Note that since the plugin makes use of the `%` file specifier, it must be updated on every file change the match the new current file. To get this, I added

```
autocmd BufFilePost compiler msbuild
```

to my vimrc file.

## Conclusion

I know that my current solution is not perfect (and I am open to any suggestion) but it now works for me to the point that Vim has now become usable in my job context. If I refine it further in the future, I'll share my findings here.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Don't you need to call the corresponding vsvars64.bat before you start Vim. Did you found an alternative solution for that?

Comment: It seems like I was able to build without it. May be it had already been called on my setup by the ITs... Not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Not really the answer you are looking for but I thought I'd share it in case anyone finds it useful. Whenever I have to use Visual Studio, the first thing I do is to register gVim as an external tool.

In Tools -> External Tools... -> Add

```
Title: Edit in Vim
Command: C:\path\to\gvim.exe
Arguments: $(ItemDir)/$(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt) +$(CurLine)
Initial Directory: $(ItemDir)
```

The second thing I do is to [assign a keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930468/custom-tool-shortcut-visual-studio) so I can quickly open the current file in Vim.

This hack uses Visual Studio for what it's good at (jumping between files, building, burning RAM and CPU cycles) and Vim only for editing.

For any serious development work, I'd invest more time to make Vim work.

On the pro side, it's set up in thirty seconds and uses the real Vim instead of a compatibility layer that's broken somewhere.

Comment: I already have this setup, I confirm it is a must for big editing work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answer will satisfy you, but here are some
ideas:

### Use neovim with `telescope`

I'd recommend to switch to `neovim` (which should be like no effort in most
cases) and install the [`telescope`](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) plugin. It should be very fast for fuzzy
finding files.

### Use neovim with `overseer.nvim`

[`overseer`](https://github.com/stevearc/overseer.nvim) is a neat task runner-plugin with some predefined task-executions
(in this case even for make) which works for me.
You can see a [demo here](https://github.com/stevearc/overseer.nvim#quick-start).

### The grep problem

I don't know if this options is available for `vim`, but it is in `neovim`.
I have the following setting:

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep\ --no-heading
```

it will let me use `rg` instead of `grep` if I do `:grep`. Doing `:grep` will be
the same as if I'd call `rg --vimgrep --no-heading` in the terminal and since
`rg` [seems to be faster than `grep`](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/#code-search-benchmarks), it should improve your experience I hope.

### Using an alias to fuzzy-search and open files.

I've the following alias in my `zsh` config:

```
alias ef="fzf | read yeet; if [[ \$yeet != '' ]]; then $EDITOR \$yeet; fi"
```

you'll have to install [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) for this.
You just need to press `ef` (which means "**e**ditor **f**ind"), it opens up
`fzf`, you can fuzzy-search the file and it will automatically open up your
editor with the given file you selected.

Comment: RE: `rg` https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/c6f2912e8ca025a5ec44dcc519d0cdcfba6c96fd/links/vim/plugin/rg.vim#L9

Comment: @Friedrich thanks for pointing that out; I'm not sure why that file is different from the rest

Comment: I am not using `neovim`, but your `grep` solution is neat. This is what I'll use from now on. Also, for fuzzy finding, I am not using CtrlP, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## Search an identifier

I recommend to install [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (and optionally the [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) plugin - the answer of @TornaxO7 explains how you can make the `:grep` command use `rg`) to have a faster search engine than the builtin `vimgrep`.

To search your identifier `youridentifier` in all the source files you could use the Vim command:

```
:Ack! -g*.cpp -g*.h youridentifier
```

**Remark**: On a project with 5,368 file and 2,282,861 lines the search takes about 1 second on my machine.

Other solution exist:

- [Silver Search](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (aka `ag`) is an alternative to [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (aka `rg`)

## Compile a file

To compile one file from a full solution you can do:

```
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /t:ClCompile /p:SelectedFiles=yourcpp.cpp
```

Assuming you want to compile: `yourscpp.cpp` for the `Release` configuration and the `x64` platform that is part of a VisualStudio project with a solution file `yoursolution.sln`

I would create a `make.bat` file in the root of the project structure with the following content:

```
setlocal
set solution=yoursolution.sln
set configuration="Release"
set platform="x64"

msbuild %solution% /p:Configuration=%configuration% /p:Platform=%platform% /t:ClCompile /p:SelectedFiles="%1"
```

You can compile the current file with the following Vim command:

```
:make %:t
```

To avoid the miss interpretation of some of the output of `msbuild` I propose to run the following two commands:

```
set errorformat^=%+GTime\ Elapsed%.%#
set errorformat^=%+GBuild\ started%.%#
```

To strip the format to the bare minimum you can add run additionally the following command:

```
set errorformat+=%-G%.%#
```

In order to ease this operation, you can override the `msbuild` compiler by adding a `msbuild.vim` file into `~\vimfiles\compiler` with the following content:

```
setlocal errorformat=%f(%l):%m

" Skip lines that starts with a whitespace
setlocal errorformat^=%-G\ %.%#

" Keep Build started
setlocal errorformat^=%+GBuild\ started%.%#
" Keep Time Elapsed
setlocal errorformat^=%+GTime\ Elapsed%.%#

" Skip all the other lines
setlocal errorformat+=%-G%.%#
```

Instead of executing the three set command you can just call `:compiler msbuild`

## Language Server Protocol (LSP)

Not strictly part of the question but I can't resist to recommend [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) together with `clangd`.

After coc.nvim installation run: `:CocInstall coc-clangd`

You'll get:

- Warnings
- Go to definition `gd`
- ...

Comment: See Tornax's answer for why you don't need a plugin for ripgrep. Just set `grepprg` and `grepformat` (https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/c6f2912e8ca025a5ec44dcc519d0cdcfba6c96fd/links/vim/plugin/rg.vim#L9).

Comment: `:let &errorformat .= …`

Comment: @Ben if I'm not wrong the `.=` operator will add the pattern  at the end of the format where I would like to insert it at the beginning.  To insert it at the end I prefer to use the `set +=` form. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are correct. Perhaps `let … ^= …`, but that might only work with `set`

Comment: Good answer. In case anyone's interested, I once wrote a vim command that would take the path to the solution file and `set makeprg=msbuild ...`. This would be a way to use `:make` without a BAT file.

Comment: Looks very promising, can't wait to try this.

Comment: Identifier searching works well using `rg` (I used @TornaxO7's solution). I was looking for fuzzy finding, and tweaking CtrlP did the job, in the end. For compiling a file, this solution does not work for me. I get the following error message: `msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: Do you start Vim from a develpper command line? Or do you start vsvars.bat before starting Vim. For the `msbuild` to work well some VS script need to run first.

Comment: I made some progress on this: it turns out msbuild was missing in my path env var. I added it and then could invoke it from anywhere. I was able to "build" from vim using your solution but for now, the build seems to always succeed ("Build succeeded") even when I add intentional mistakes. I'll keep working on it but I'm making progress whenever I have time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe only adding build to the path is not enough. Visual Studio comes with a special script (e.g.: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` for Visual Studio 2022) that you have to call to make the `msbuild` and its friends available. I strongly advice to use it ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: I was able to get something working with your help. I have posted my own answer, but don't worry I have set a bounty which I will award to your answer to thank you for your patience and input. I will be awarded in the next few days, as soon as the grace period is over.